# c# vs javascript: Datetime.Now.Ticks vs Date.now() returns different values

Tags: javascript, c#

I thought with the c# call:

```
var x = DateTime.Now.Ticks
```

and with the Javascript call:

```
var x = Date.now()
```

I should be getting the same result.

But on c# I am getting: 637593006969672760

While Javascript returns: 1623750547564

(Those are not from the same day, but should be extermely close. However, both values differ by A LOT)

I thought both return the value of miliseconds since the first of jan 0:00 of 1970?

So why are both values so different?
And how can I translate the c# call to javascript?

Comment: Why do you think they should be the same? `Date.now()` (lowercase n) returns the number of milliseconds that have passed since the UNIX epoch https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now

Comment: And C# does what? I thought it should be the same. How can I make the javascript call be the same as the c# call=

Comment: `DateTime.Now.Ticks()` seems to count the number of nano seconds since the UNIX epoch.

Comment: `I thought it should be the same.` Why did you think that?

Comment: @evolutionxbox your right. So my question shoule be: how can I get the same value in javascript?

Comment: Unless you can coordinate both languages to execute down to the same nano second, you can't.

Comment: please read [The Manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.ticks?view=net-5.0) before making assumptions. thank you. and what you _want_ to use is [DateTimeOffset.ToUnixTimeMIlliseconds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.tounixtimemilliseconds?view=net-5.0) is it really _that_ far-fetched of an idea to read the documentation before asking on stack-overflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For c# `Ticks`:

> The value of this property represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001 in the Gregorian calendar

For Javascript `Date`:

> JavaScript Date objects represent a single moment in time in a platform-independent format. Date objects contain a Number that represents milliseconds since 1 January 1970 UTC.

Sources:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.ticks?view=net-5.0
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

---

In C# to get the number of milliseconds since some point in time (eg 1/1/1970) you could use:

```
var datum = new DateTime(1970,1,1);
var msSinceDatum = DateTime.Now.Subtract(datum).TotalMilliseconds;
```

Having run that a few seconds ago it gave the answer `1623751729961.4617` whereas the `DateTime.now()` in javascript gave `1623751739058`. Should be close enough for your needs.

---

Note you can also use [`DateTimeOffset.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.tounixtimemilliseconds?view=net-5.0)

```
var msSinceUnix = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
```

---

Going the other way (C# ticks to javascript date) is a little more involved.

```js
var ticks = 637593490842364954; // ticks retrieved a few moments ago
var ticksToMicrotime = ticks / 10000;
var epochMicrotimeDiff = Math.abs(new Date(0, 0, 1).setFullYear(1)); 
var date = new Date(ticksToMicrotime - epochMicrotimeDiff);
console.log(date)
```

Comment: Your right. How can I get the same value in javascript since 0001?

Comment: @JuTo you can't. Javascript date doesnt go back that far

Comment: Could I maybe just "add" the remaining ticks to make the dates the same? I have to match the code used from c# with my javascript application (web), So I need to get to values that are at least close.

Comment: @JuTo maybe the update solves your problem

Comment: Hey thank you. This is just exactly the other way round: the application in c# came first. So all dates are recorded since year 0 basically. I need my javascript date to match that. :)

Comment: Am I wrong to assume that, since there are 621.355.968.000.000.000 Ticks between 1970 and year 0, I can just add this constant to Date.now() ?

Comment: @JuTo sample added to go from ticks to JS date